# Controlling for multilevel structure CLPM

Tags: cross-correlation, centering

I want to run an CLPM and have some questions regarding the clustered structure (school classes) of my data. I learned that centering can account for the nested data structure, but it is only recommended to center independent variables.

In a CLPM, except for the first measurement point, all variables are independent variables, am I right that centering is not the best strategy in this case? Is it sufficient to control for the nested structure by using eg the type = complex command in MPlus with cluster= class?